# SAML 2.0 on .net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am implementing a saml2.0 on a .NET 4.0 what do you recommend on building the metadata for Service Provider ? How should I build it. and the certificate How could I generate on a production environment

I do not want to upgrade the application to 4.5 yet as it can have an effect to some implementation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .NET 4.0 do not implement the needed SAML 2.0 token handling and signing functionality required for implementing the SAML 2.0 standard. These needed functionalities first came in .NET 4.5.

The ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 packaged add support for the SAML 2.0 standard on top of the functionality implemented in .NET. The package is really a thin rapper adding extra functionality.

There are maybe other SAML 2.0 implementation which have implemented the holde SAML 2.0 standard without relying on the .NET functionality and thereby support .NET 4.0.